# How to get haskell compiler version within code?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I suspect there is a way, but couldn't find it.. E.g something like this:

```hs
import GHC.Version qualified

main :: IO ()
main = print $ GHC.Version.current
-- would print Version 8 10 7
```

**Edit**

The suggested CPP macro `__GLASGOW_HASKELL__` can be used to have CPP if/else clauses but that would be a rather long list of conditionals to determine the exact version. But something along the lins of `main = print __GLASGOW_HASKELL__` doesn't seem to be possible (?).

Comment: What goes wrong when you try `main = print __GLASGOW_HASKELL__`? Works fine here.

Comment: Dumb question, but you did do `{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}` still, right? If you got errors about ambiguous types and found hole, then that's what you forgot.

Comment: You were both right, the part in the edit does work. I forgot the CPP pragma in the second round. I asked the same question also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71708850/how-to-get-haskell-compiler-version-within-code-without-a-long-list-of-cpp-if-el, (because this one was marked as a duplicate)