# How to get haskell compiler version within code without a long list of CPP if/else conditionals?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Something along the lines of:

```hs
import GHC.Version qualified

main :: IO ()
main = print $ GHC.Version.current
-- would print Version 8 10 7
```

A roundabout way is to execute `ghc --version` from shell:

```hs
import System.Process

main = system "ghc --version"
```

but this may be incorrect when the running GHC isn't the same as the `ghc` in `PATH`.

Comment: The linked question is about GHCi, but the answers also cover your case. Also see the docs https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.1.0/docs/System-Info.html

Comment: Right, the `System.Info.compilerVersion` is the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @chi But why mark it as duplicate as the question really is not? Ghci can have other means to print a version.

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate because the answers from the other question would still apply. I agree that GHCi could have other ways e.g. a `:printVersion` command.  OTOH, keeping two questions open with basically the same answer feels weird. I am not 100% convinced about the best thing to do here. If you think this is better kept open, and no one objects, I will revert my close vote.

Comment: @chi True that the answer is contained in the other question, but the question is different (same with the CPP pragma question posted initially). Hmm, would like to answer the current question or the inital one, but if something is marked as a duplicate then at least I myself can't post an answer. Both solutions work (the `System.Info.compilerVersion` and also `__GLASGOW_HASKELL__`), and would make a nice Q&A pair.

Comment: It would be really interesting to see how far you could get using just changes to language extensions that affect type inference and changes that introduce or fix bugs in run-time behavior.

Comment: Didn’t someone collect code snippets that change behavior based on language extension? Can’t find it right now … ah, maybe it was this: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/153744/wait-what-language-is-this

Comment: @dfeuer, Joachim Breitner Did SO glitch here, I don't see how your comments relate to my question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in two ways. The first using [`System.Info.compilerVersion`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/System-Info.html#v:compilerVersion)

```hs
import System.Info

main :: IO ()
main = print compilerVersion
-- prints "Version {versionBranch = [8,6], versionTags = []}"
```

Second via the `CPP` language extension:

```html
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

main :: IO ()
main = print __GLASGOW_HASKELL__
-- prints "806" (of type Integer)
```

[Docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/phases.html#standard-cpp-macros) on how that number has been come up with.

Comment: (Both of these answers were actually found by @chi who first marked my question as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28292476/ghc-version-check-in-code and then as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67798337/can-i-find-the-ghc-version-from-inside-ghci)